# Celsius to Farenheit Conversion Always Showing Zeros Under Celsius Scale

Tags: c, algorithm

I have been returning to C programming recently and I am starting with some simple exercises. However, when I have tried to run a Farenheit to Celsius conversion programme that I wrote the Farenheit column renders well but the Celsius column is always calculated as being zero. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int step;
    int upper;
    float farenheit;
    float celsius;

    step = 20;
    upper = 300;

    celsius = 0.0;
    farenheit = 0.0;

    printf("Farenheit \t Celsius\n");

    while(farenheit <= upper)
    {

        celsius = ((farenheit - 32.0) * 5.0) / 9.0;
        printf("\n%6f \t %6.1f\n", farenheit, celsius);

        farenheit = farenheit + step;
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

The output comes out as follows:

```
Farenheit        Celsius

     0   -0.000000

    20   -0.000000

    40   0.000000

    60   0.000000

    80   0.000000

   100   0.000000

   120   0.000000

   140   0.000000

   160   0.000000

   180   0.000000

   200   0.000000

   220   0.000000

   240   0.000000

   260   0.000000

   280   0.000000

   300   0.000000


------------------
(program exited with code: 0)
Press return to continue
```

I see that others have encountered this problem as well, and they have fixed it by appending the appropriate zeros to values that are meant to be floating point. However, this does not seem to work for me and I am not sure what is the problem here. I am using the Geany Linux Integrated Development Environment for this code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This program works as-is on my machine. Would you mind making sure that you did recompile the code after making the changes, or possibly trying to invoke `gcc` or similar directly?

Comment: Also, that output does not seem to match the conversion specifiers in the format string; could output be from different code than that posted?

Comment: I checked on [ideone](https://ideone.com/gT1JtQ) and can confirm both of the above comments.

Comment: Delete the executable and try to recreate it.

Comment: Just as an experiment, change step to 25 and try again.

Comment: I have found the solution to the problem. I am deeply sorry for wasting everyone's time. It looks like in the IDE the compile and build functions are separate and so one can compile a file but then the build operation needs to be carried out to create an executable. Now everything is working fine.

Comment: @TheContextualPath -- [Don't indicate that a problem has been solved in question titles.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311829/why-cant-i-mark-my-title-as-solved) In general, this discourages others from providing possibly better answers, and there is already a mechanism for showing that a problem has been solved: accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark next to it. You can accept your own answer, if you wish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the Integrated Development Environment compiler is buggy. I compiled my source code using the command line with gcc syntax and when I ran the programme everything worked as expected compared to what I had experienced with the in-built compiler. It looks like my problem has been solved. But, it is interesting that there is such a problem with the IDE compiler. However, I would like to thank everyone for their input into this problem.

Edit: Aha! The problem was actually very simple. I deeply apologise for wasting everyone's time. It looks like it had nothing to do with a buggy compiler, but for the fact that when I hit compile using the IDE it does not create an executable. In order for me to run the programme properly, I must Compile it and then select an option to Build it.

I see that in the Geany IDE for files that are compiled in the C# programming language, the Compile option both compiles the file or files and builds an executable at the same time. While for files that are compiled in the C programming language Geany changes the options available to make separate the Compile and Build functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Your program, as is, works fine for me. I used GCC to compile it. I find it weird that in your output the Fahrenheit shows without the 6 decimal digits as it is the default. And your Celsius output also does not follow your format of 1 decimal point. I blame your compiler for this error. I have no experience Geany Linux though.

Answer (score -2):

Your having casting issues, as fahrenheit is a float, but it's being compared to an int, which is likely causing your problem.

```
float step;
float upper;
float farenheit;
float celsius;

step = 20.0;
upper = 300.0;

celsius = 0.0;
farenheit = 0.0;

printf("Farenheit \t Celsius\n");

while(farenheit <= upper) {

    celsius = ((farenheit - 32.0) * 5.0) / 9.0;
    printf("\n%6f \t %6.1f\n", farenheit, celsius);

    farenheit = farenheit + step;
}   

return 0;
```